# How to load otg from Bim360?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I would like to to read my bim360 models which is in otg format in my Forgeviewer (version 7.3). The projects have been converted using the https://otg-bim.herokuapp.com/ app.

Is there any guidelines of how to make my Forge viewer read otg format from Bim360? I found this guideline (https://github.com/wallabyway/OTG-client-sample/blob/552c78b1fe8e1177f6694fd947a17fd189a8505b/public/js/ForgeViewer.js#L26-L29), however it uses Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication which I find in version 2 of the Forge API, but not in version 7.3.

Comment: Let me update this and send a PR to the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of svf2 works fine when using buckets instead of bim360. I have not vertified it with bim360. Example code which was helpfull for me was this npm package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-adsk-forge-viewer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this version of the ForgeViewer.js to work with latest versions of the viewer. https://github.com/jaimerosales/OTG-client-sample/blob/master/public/js/ForgeViewer.js

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is the same svn. Fault was that options requires autorization, even though I am allready autorized through bim360 login. Providing the access token there, uncomment useCookie and useCrentials and it works.

```
 const options = {
    env: 'FluentProduction',
    api: 'fluent',
    //useCookie: false,  
    //useCredentials: false,
    accessToken: "add access token even though you are allready authorized in in bim360"
  };
```

So far, I have seen a significant improvement loading using otg :-).